# Let value changes out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

Can someone please explain to me, why **start** and **end** variables print to console different values for these loggers? 
I get printed out: 
start1 = Mon Feb 17 2020 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) 
end1 = Mon Feb 17 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) 
start2 = Mon Feb 17 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) 
end2 = Mon Feb 17 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) 

I want to add, that the code I presented is in some method of course, and the names **start** and **end** don't interfere with other variable names.

```
let start = this.service.getDateTime(
  eventFromUi.start_date,
  eventFromUi.start_time_hour,
  eventFromUi.start_time_minute
);
console.log("start1 = " + start);
let end = this.service.getDateTime(
  eventFromUi.start_date,
  eventFromUi.end_time_hour,
  eventFromUi.end_time_minute
);
console.log("end1 = " + end);
console.log("start2 = " + start);
console.log("end2 = " + end);
```

EDIT: 
The getDateTime() method returns object of TypeScript ootb type Date. 
I used Chrome debugger to look into this, and I see that when I first execute the getDateTime() method, I get value *Mon Feb 17 2020 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)* returned and assigned to let **start**. 
Then the method getDateTime() is executed again and retuns value *Mon Feb 17 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)*, and this value gets assigned to both **start** and **end** variables. 
How does this happen?

EDIT2: 
Function getDateTime:

```
getDateTime(dateWithoutTime: Date, hour: number, minute: number): Date {
    let date = dateWithoutTime;
    console.log(date);
    console.log(hour);
    console.log(minute);
    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(minute);
    return date;
  }
```

Comment: What if you print it a third time? It seems very odd that it would change like that. Are those both regular strings? Have you stepped through in a JavaScript debugger to see if they flip?

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that code exactly as posted would show such results.

Comment: @tadman I have updated the question in edit, I am answering there to you. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Pointy I have updated the question with additional details

Comment: Well what exactly does this `getDateTime()` function look like? It's possible that it attempts some kind of caching that's updating the same Date instance instead of making a new one.

Comment: If you want to lock it down, maybe call `.toString()`? If this is an object and not a string the way it's rendered out *could* change.

Comment: Updated again. @tadman I don't really want to use `.toString()`, because I later assigned both dates to one custom **event** object that requires **Date** fields **start** and **end** that I then send to rest endpoint and work on dto there on the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you're dealing with object references.

```
getDateTime(dateWithoutTime: Date, hour: number, minute: number): Date {
    let date = dateWithoutTime;
    // date is now a copy of the *reference* to the same object that
    // dateWithoutTime is a reference to. In other words: it is pointing
    // to the same object in memory

    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(minute);
    // since date is pointing to the same object as dateWithoutTime, this is
    // modifying both date and dateWithoutTime

    return date;
  }
```

This also means that in your code, `eventFromUi.start_date`, `start` and `end` are all references pointing to *the same Date object*.

To solve your problem, make sure you create a *clone* of `dateWithoutTime` when it is passed into your function:

```
getDateTime(dateWithoutTime: Date, hour: number, minute: number): Date {
    let date = new Date(dateWithoutTime);
    // date is now a reference to a *new Date object* with the same
    // date/time/etc. values as dateWithoutTime

    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(minute);
    // since date now points to a new object, this is only modifying date
    // while leaving dateWithoutTime alone and unchanged

    return date;
  }
```

Comment: This is it! Of course, makes perfect sense. Thank you!